# Angular 4 refresh page route issue

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i am newbie in Angularjs 4. When i refresh page then my app couldn't find `inline.bundle.js, pollyfills.bundle.js,etc`. I thinks it is path problem but not sure.

I am trying to explain the issue i.e, my app run at `localhost:4200` and i can access module `localhost:4200/user/profile` from menu but when i refresh page then not found error generate.  I see image below.

[Please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgjU.png)

Comment: use can use  #hash location strategy.  `RouterModule.forRoot([...], { useHash: true});`

Comment: I am guessing this is for production? You need to make sure that all urls starts the angular application. You can add redirection rules to your server configuration maybe?